# Checking array for blacklisted charecters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that is unknown on each run i have this function

```
function checkIllegal(args, refuse) {
        var block = fs.readFileSync(`block.txt`, 'utf-8');
        var refuse = block.split(',');
        var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        for (let i = 0; i < refuse.length; i++) {
          for (let j = 0; j < args.length; j++) {
            console.log(refuse[i], args[j])
            if (args[j].includes(refuse[i])) {
              console.log("Blacklisted")
              illegal = "true";
            }
          }
        }
        illegal = "false";
        return false;
      } // Check for illegal arguments.
```

It finds the blacklisted characters but only when there isnt multiple
for example it will block if there is one ; but not if there are two like ;;

How can i fix this and get it to work?

NOTE: The given answer below works but only with a hard coded array.

Comment: What do you mean "when there are no multiple"?

Comment: Can you share an example of what the content of the file is

Comment: ```>,>>,>,&,|,;,``` @Tikkes

Comment: `Blacklisted` is not a good name. Maybe `not allowed` is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build `refuse` and `args` arrays outside of the function and pass them as parameters.

```js
const refuse = [">", ";", "&", ","]
const args = [">>>>", ";;;;;;", "&&", ",,"]


function checkIllegal(refuse, args) {
  let illegal = false;
  refuse.forEach(e => {
    args.forEach(string => {
      if (string.includes(e)) illegal = true;
      console.log("Blacklisted");
    });
  });
  return illegal;
}

console.log(checkIllegal(refuse, args));
```

This still returns true or false **based on the whole array not for every single string**, is that what you need?

Otherwise I would not loop through the args inside the function but outside of it, then you could check for every String.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/x24qnes6/

The below solution does work for both single and multiple characters

```js
function isRefused() {
  const refuse = ">,>>,>,&,|,;,".split(',')
  const args = "; ;; | > << >>".trim().split(/ +/g);
  let illegal = false;
   refuse.forEach(r => {
      args.forEach(a => {
        if (a.includes(r)) {
          console.log(`${a} is blacklisted`)
          illegal = true;
        }
      })
    })
  return illegal;
}

console.log(`Blacklisted? ${isRefused()}`)
```

You have to check the other way around.
Does `args[j]` have `refused[i]`

A better way however would be using a regex for this.

Comment: It actually opens a txt and gets a long list of strings and chars that get added onto frequently i didnt think regex would suit an ever changing list.

Comment: This isnt working either when i test it with a hard coded array it works but with without it dosent.

Comment: Share more of the code then because like this it is impossible for me to help you further

Comment: updated, this should work perfectly fine. My guess is that you don't return the actual illegal when it is set to true